# Access the root for Samsungs Galaxy S7 Micro SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, galaxy

I have a problem to access the sd card on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

I added in the manifest the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What I tried to access the sd card is to get the absolute path with:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

and it shows me the path: /storage/emulated/0

But with this path, I can not access my files on the sd card.

I also tried different answers including "external_sd", "sdcard", using "sdcard0", "sdcard1", but nothing is working for me.

Then I tried to loop over the folders in the /storage/

```
    File dir = new File("/storage/");

    ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()){

            fileNames.add(f.getName());
        }
    }

    Log.d("file", fileNames.toString());
```

The Log shows

```
[3333-3733, emulated, enc_emulated, self]
```

I found out, that my files I want to access are in the folder 3333-3733.

So what is the correct way to access the sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end I used the function

```
public File getExternalSdCard() {
    File externalStorage = null;
    File storage = new File("/storage");

    if(storage.exists()) {
        File[] files = storage.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
                        externalStorage = file;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return externalStorage;
}
```

to get my sd card.

This is very sad.